# Possible to limit number of cups printers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cups

The way I have configured CUPS on my workstation is by

```
echo 'CUPS_SERVER=cups.example.com' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export CUPS_SERVER' >> ~/.profile
```

When I open the print menu in any program I see ~50 CUPS printers, where I am only interested in 2-3 of them.

**Question**

Is it possible to only show those 2-3 printers I am interested in?

Comment: How would you like to filter? By user? By group? By IP subnet? By location?

Comment: Ideally by name. IP subnet might also work.